# Panner node deprecation/update confusion

Tags: web-audio-api

The `audioContext.listener` is deprecated and in place is a "spatialListener" and I am curious if it is still a property of the audio context?

In other words is the syntax:   `audioContext.spatialListener` ?

Also, it is not clear what the difference is between the `pannerNode` and the `spatialPanner` node at this point. Any clarifying would be appreciated.If spatialPanner is replacing the previous panner node then what role does the previous pannerNode have if any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are currently three panners:

1. StereoPanner.  This is a simple, equal power panner with a left/right balance AudioParam.  Most non-3D panning scenarios should probably use this - it's simple, lightweight and works well for speakers and headphones.
2. Panner.  This is the previous panner with x/y/z controls (and the listener to set up the listener position and orientation).  Unfortunately, the x/y/z/ controls weren't set up as AudioParams, and it was too late to change them in-place: every bit of code out there using Panner would have broken.  (Same with Listener: the params needed to be AudioParams, not doubles: that's why there is now SpatialListener.)  This node is deprecated, and will go away: hopefully before v1 of the Web Audio spec is finalized.  This supports both equal-power and HRTF (head-related transfer function), which enables 3D positioning.
3. SpatialPanner.  This is basically the same as #2, except a) it uses AudioParams for the parameters, so it's smoothly automatable, b) it's relative to the SpatialListener, which also uses AudioParams, and c) it's not deprecated.  :)  If you're not using StereoPanner, you should probably use SpatialPanner and SpatialListener.

Comment: Thanks Chris , Is spatialListener a property of the audio context like listener ?

Comment: When i try to create a Spatial Panner with the following code it returns an error and simply isn't recognized as a function.       var panner = audioContext.createSpatialPanner();

Comment: I don't think anyone has implemented this yet.  Hopefully, Chrome will implement it soon.

Comment: William:  yes, spatialListener should be an AudioContext property.  I noticed, however, that it's not, so I filed a bug.  :)  https://github.com/WebAudio/web-audio-api/issues/714